# What electromagnetic wave produces the strongest electrical current when making contact with an element?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, power

More specifically, what electromagnetic waves can we utilize to generate electrical power and out of those waves, which one would produce the most power? Additionally, which one would be the most reasonably accessible and usable?

Note: The reason I ask this question is because I was wondering what kind of wave we could use in order to have, lets say, wireless laptop chargers and what not.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is either: what FREQUENCY of alternating current, as in the case of a local open core transformer, or else what frequency of RF energy (as in microwave, radio wave, etc.) could be used to power or provide charge to laptops batteries 'wirelessly'?

Not just any frequency you want, that's for sure.  In the United States, the FCC takes a dim view of manufacturers using radio or microwave radiation for such purposes, because it may interfere with communication uses of such bandwidth (cellphones or even more vital uses), which is likely to have already been allocated for that purpose.

If you are asking about very short range charging (like is done with many brands of electric toothbrushes), that's usually in the range of 100 kHz, because the ferrite materials of the open core transformers are reasonably efficient at those frequencies, and short range enough not to interfere with communications.

Answer (score 0):

Ultraviolet would be the best the short wavelengths carry a lot of energy.

Comment: You also have to consider the emission and capture mechanisms... Gamma rays carry more than UV but are hard to harness for work.

Comment: True but gamma rays will take quite a considerable amount of effort when it comes to containment and production .